# Wordpress: NGINX-Rewrite Rule Probleme

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, nginx

This was my htaccess on apache:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Now i switched to nging and i looks like this:

## REWRITE RULE

```
if (!-f $request_filename){
    set $rule_1 1$rule_1;
}
if (!-d $request_filename){
    set $rule_1 2$rule_1;
}
if ($rule_1 = "21"){
    rewrite /. /index.php last;
}
```

This works but with wp-admin i have to many redirects, can anybody help me?

Thanks

Comment: Your implementation is archaic. Have you seen [this recipe](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/)? The rewrite rule is implemented in `nginx` by `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;`